# Ruby Iterator - define a method that accepts an array and a string

Tags: ruby

I want to define a method that accept an array, and a string, then it should find all the strings in the array that starts with the string that was supplied: example array["Jamaica","Japan","USA","China"]; if the string supplied is Ja, then it should return Jamaica and Japan

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? Do you have any code or did you want us to do it for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's very important to show what work you've done to solve the problem. Without that we'll be shooting in the dark, trying to recreate your code and problem, then fixing it. You'd have to shoehorn that code back into your codebase, which is very error prone. Plus, without your example code it looks like you're fishing for someone to write code for you, which is a great way to get your question closed and downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `keep_if` and regex :

```
["Jamaica","Japan","USA","China"].keep_if { |c| c =~ /^ja/i }

# returns ["Jamaica", "Japan"]
```

It's a static example. To create the regex dynamically, do `Regexp.new("^#{your_var}", true)`

Comment: String has to start with 'ja', not just include it.

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill but it would work quickly for huge arrays. Lucky for you, I just yesterday stumbled upon  a new high speed trie library for ruby called [TRIEZ](https://github.com/luikore/triez). Run `gem install triez` then from their example switched up a little bit:

```
require 'triez'
countries = ["Jamaica","Japan","USA","China"]
t = Triez.new
countries.each do |word|
  t[word] = 1
end

ja_countries = []
t.search_with_prefix 'Ja' do |suffix|
  ja_countries += "Ja#{suffix}"
end
```

It's implemented in C so I bet it's fast as hell on huge arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The most important methods for an Array are not found in the documentation for Array, but on that for [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html). You are searching for a method which *finds all* elements which comply to some condition.

This condition was that the string *starts with* some characters. Wouldn't it be nice if a [string object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) had a method for that?

Comment: i like where you are headed. one comment, the difference between `finds_all` and `keep_if` is `finds_all` maps to a new array where `keep_if` deletes elements from the original. this can make a huge difference in performance when working with big arrays, but is probably insignificant here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using many different things, if you don' want to modify the array you can use the select method from Array Class.

```
["Jamaica","Japan","USA","China"].select{|item| item.match("Ja")}
```

The Array will be intact.